# OpenVPN not listening on port

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, port

I setup an OpenVPN server on my RaspberryPi (Raspbian). Started successfully, but it is not listening to the port, so connecting to it is not possible. I can't find the problem here? What do I do wrong?

- `cat /etc/openvpn/vpn-server.conf`

  > port 11094
  >   proto udp
  >   dev tun
  >   ca ca.crt
  >   cert vpn-server.crt
  >   key vpn-server.key
  >   dh dh2048.pem
  >   server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
  >   ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
  >   push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
  >   push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
  >   push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
  >   keepalive 10 120
  >   tls-auth ta.key 0
  >   key-direction 0
  >   cipher AES-128-CBC
  >   auth SHA256
  >   comp-lzo
  >   user nobody
  >   group nogroup
  >   persist-key
  >   persist-tun
  >   status openvpn-status.log
  >   log /var/log/openvpn.log
  >   verb 6
- `sudo netstat -vaun`

  > Active Internet connections (servers and established)
  >   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
  >   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11094           0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:123         0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 10.8.0.1:123            0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43721           0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
  >   udp6       0      0 :::44058                :::*
  >   udp6       0      0 fe80::6d3d:f08e:c6b:123 :::*
  >   udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*
  >   udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
  >   udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
- `nmap -sU 10.8.0.1 -p 11094`

  > Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-16 17:04 UTC
  >   Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.1
  >   Host is up.
  >   PORT      STATE         SERVICE
  >   11094/udp open|filtered unknown
- `cat /var/log/openvpn.log`

  > Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 27 2017
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 ROUTE: default_gateway=UNDEF
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 GID set to nogroup
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 UID set to nobody
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
  >   Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
- `sudo systemctl status openvpn@vpn-server`

  > ● openvpn@vpn-server.service - OpenVPN connection to vpn-server
  >   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled)
  >   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-02-16 15:47:29 UTC; 1h 10min ago
  >   Process: 499 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  >   Main PID: 547 (openvpn)
  >   CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@vpn-server.service
  >          └─547 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-vpn-server --status /run/openvpn/vpn-server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpn-server.conf
  >   Feb 16 15:47:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to vpn-server...
  >   Feb 16 15:47:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to vpn-server.
  >   Feb 16 16:06:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to vpn-server.

Comment: What is your local subnet? Is it 192.168.1.0 /24?

Comment: yes, 192.168.1.0/24. Also now from the logs when trying to connect I get 
`Fri Feb 16 18:23:45 2018 us=599042 192.168.1.4:38630 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need a router in-between two /24 networks.

In your VPN config you have server address configured as 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0. that's the network, not an address.

"Fri Feb 16 15:47:29 2018 ROUTE: default_gateway=UNDEF"
And additionally you need the default gateway defined for a layer-3 device to be able to communicate outside of it's subnet. (This is the address of the router that would connect you to the 192.168.1.0 /24 subnet)

Try changing your openvpn server address to your local subnet. 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0

And put your default gateway pointing to the router you have connected.